# Response javascript do servidor, campo vindo com um method/function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

tenho um service que intercepta a response do banco e manda pro angular. Algumas "responses" do servidor vem com por exemplo um objeto com um campo $id: function(), porém na response o id vem certo, quando eu pego essa response e jogo ela em um array no campo id ela vem 'function()' em vez do resultado que estava na response, por que isso?

Answer (score 0):

Seria uma injeção de código (JS) ?

Caso seja você precisa executar o "eval":

```
eval("(function(){ alert('Hello!'); })()");
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea

Abraço!